# Problem in translation display in translation app on android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

Hello eveyone i hope you are all doing good. I have a little problem and I couldn't find the solution. I have a translation app and after the user input his phrase by a record, the translation message doesn't appear. So I hope that someone could help me.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:hint="Tap Mic to Speak"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/idBtnTranslateLanguage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TransledText"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Translate language" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_mic_24" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TransledText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Translated language"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

And my main code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.ml.common.modeldownload.FirebaseModelDownloadConditions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.FirebaseNaturalLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslateLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslator;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslatorOptions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private static final int CodeSpeechInput =100;
private TextView EditText;
private ImageButton SpeakButton;
private TextView TransledText;
FirebaseTranslator englishFrenshTranslator;
private Button translateLanguageBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseTranslatorOptions options =
            new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                    .setSourceLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.EN)
                    .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.FR)
                    .build();

    englishFrenshTranslator = FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);


    EditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    SpeakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TransledText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TransledText);
    translateLanguageBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnTranslateLanguage);

    translateLanguageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String string = EditText.getText().toString();
            downloadModal(string);
        }

        private void downloadModal(String input) {
            FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder().requireWifi().build();
            englishFrenshTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    // this method is called when modal is downloaded successfully.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please wait language modal is being downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // calling method to translate our entered text.
                    translateLanguage(input);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to download modal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

                private void translateLanguage(String input) {
                    englishFrenshTranslator.translate(input).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String result) {
                            TransledText.setText(input);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to translate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }


            });

    SpeakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startVoiceInput();
        }

        private void startVoiceInput() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, CodeSpeechInput);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

            }
        }




    });


}
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CodeSpeechInput : {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    EditText.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I also use firebase if that could help you.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Actually their are no errors, just the translated text doesn't show up

Comment: Is any of the listeners triggered?